# Refresh not working for static page in dotnet core 3

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

Whenever I'm trying to save the static cshtml file and refresh the browser the changes are not getting affected, each time I have to stop the project and re-run it to get work.

I'm using the latest visual studio 2019 with .net core 3.1.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-compilation?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, thanks to Kirk Larkin

Install **Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RuntimeCompilation** from NuGet

Then add this code in startup.cs file

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddRazorPages().AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();

}
```